# How can I make my Discord.py bot write all the members in a server to a TXT file?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

So... I've been working on a Discord bot for hours that should simply list all members of a server along with the role that comes after the "Division" role in a TXT file.
The bot does everything as it should, but I just can't solve one problem.
There are 476 members on the server, but in the TXT file, only 4 members are listed.

discord.py:

```py
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
token = os.environ['bot_token_justwait']

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {client.user}')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.channel.name == "testarmee":
        if message.content.startswith('/update'):
            server = client.get_guild(server_id)
            await message.channel.send("Retrieving member info...")
            with open("memberlist.txt", "w") as f:
                for m in server.members:
                    if not m.bot:
                        role = [r for r in m.roles][::-1]
                        for i in range(len(role) - 1):
                            if "Division" in role[i].name:
                                next_role = role[i + 1]
                                line = "{0.mention}: {0.display_name}, {1}\n".format(m, next_role.name)
                                f.write(line)
                                break
            await message.channel.send("Member data saved!")

client.run(token)
```

memberlist.txt:

```
<@938484743194951730>: [Lima-02] Odolf Hadler, Luftwaffe
<@778961048166072344>: [EK-01] Erwin Rommel, Einzelkämpfer
<@753889789152854048>: [Worlock-01] Maurice Mort, Luftwaffe
<@697743777733017741>: [Lima-04] Frank Reich, Luftwaffe
```

I've tried everything and asked in chat GPT, but no matter what I change, it always stops after 3 to 6 members... I really don't understand what the problem is, and apparently no one has had this issue before. I recently started learning how to program bots, so I'm not that experienced yet. Hopefully, someone can help me...
Regards

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code, stepping through it and making sure all variables are what you think they are, and seeing why the loop stops early?

Comment: Yes of cours. I checkt everything

Comment: So what's the exact issue? When does it stop, and why?

Comment: It stops after it addet 3 to 6 members in the list but i dont understand the pattern.. maybe the bot is reading the amount of mebers in a Chanel with just 3 members but i dont know how to fix this

Comment: It sounds like you have tried to _debug_ the program, but haven't used a _debugger_. A debugger allows you to set breakpoints at certain lines of your code and then step through it line by line, showing you exactly what each variable is at that point in time. I highly suggest looking into them, as they will make troubleshooting your code much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be due to the fact that discord.py doesn't automatically fetch all members of a guild (server) due to Discord's privacy settings. After around late 2020, Discord implemented intents which are used to dictate what events a bot can and cannot listen for. This is for privacy and optimisation reasons. For large guilds, member data is not sent by default, you have to request it using the "members" intent and then requesting member data.

In your code, the intents object is created and is being set properly for the bot, however, it does not have the members intent enabled. Also, you are using both a client and bot instance which is unnecessary and may cause potential problems. Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='/', intents=intents)
token = os.environ['bot_token_justwait']

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'We have logged in as {bot.user}')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return

    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.command()
async def update(ctx):
    if ctx.channel.name == "testarmee":
        await ctx.send("Retrieving member info...")
        with open("memberlist.txt", "w") as f:
            for m in ctx.guild.members:
                if not m.bot:
                    role = [r for r in m.roles if "Division" in r.name]
                    if role:
                        next_role = role[0]
                        line = f"{m.mention}: {m.display_name}, {next_role.name}\n"
                        f.write(line)
        await ctx.send("Member data saved!")

bot.run(token)
```

Remember, in order to use the members intent, your bot has to be verified if it's in 100 or more guilds. You also need to go to the Discord Developer Portal, find your bot, go to the "Bot" tab, and under "Privileged Gateway Intents", turn on "Server Members Intent".